Difference between 本気で and 真面目に?
I know the general sentiment is that it is a condition/scope/reason/method marker and it's making more sense bit by bit through examples I've found but I'm still not grasping it entirely. What is the difference between these two? I've never understood it.
This is how I tried to make sense of it:
本気で
Doing (something) In a serious (manner) (?)
真面目に
In a serious (way) (?)

The main difference is the level of seriousness. 本気で sounds more passionate, like you're putting your whole heart into something. On the other hand, 真面目に sounds like you're doing something earnestly or diligently, without playing. While it's common to say 遊んでないで真面目に働いてください, saying 遊んでないで本気で働いてください usually sounds too strong.
